# recv() windows socket function not receiving whole buffer

Tags: c, winsock2

I am working on a server client application on windows.
My program works perfectly fine when messages sent are really small (around 20-30KB).
But the moment the size of buffer sent is greater than 50 KB, the program doesnt work.
I noticed that send() function sends exact number of bytes I wish to. But recv function doesnt receive that much. I am assuming that the network might have fragmented the buffer internally. But shouldn't I be able to receive the whole buffer after multiple recv() calls? 
I am sending the buffer through TCP, so it should ideally guarantee that I receive the whole message.
When I send a buffer of 50KB or greater, I get around 16KB in the first recv(), but the next time recv() is called I get an empty buffer. Why does the message get lost? And is there any way to get it? It happens only for buffers greater than 50KB.

I code in C using windows socket library.

Comment: It should work.  You can send any 50KB without any issues with TCP.  You most likely have a bug.  But without showing any code, it's going to be hard to tell you what's wrong.
Do you use select?  If recv returns 16KB, there is no guarantee that the next call will return the rest.  You have to wait for it to arrive.
You could use wireshark to see the actual packets and timings.

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin int recv(
  _In_   SOCKET s,
  _Out_  char *buf,
  _In_   int len,
  _In_   int flags
);
This is the definition of recv function according to MSDN. What should be the ideal value of len ? I have kept 16KB. Could that be the reason ?

Comment: The ideal value is the size of your socket buffer because this is the maximum you can recv() at one time, so it depends on the OS configuration.  64KB is probably the right size.  But no matter what size of buffer you're using, you can have a race where there is fragmention unless you either use blocking i/o or things like select

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin I am waiting on select(). The thing is when the buffer is around 30KB or so, the whole buffer arrives in 2 recv() calls, but if it is greater than 50KB, after the 1st recv() call, only empty buffers arrive :(

Comment: But do you go back to `select()` after the first `recv()` call?  You cannot call it twice in a row.  It's not guaranteed that the data is already there.

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin Yes I go back to select(). Only If data is there recv() is called..

Comment: What's the return value of `recv()` the 2nd time?

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin I don't recollect it right now. But the buffer received is empty !

Comment: Well, without code and without the return value, I can't tell you.  But if select returns your fd as readable, it has to be readable (or some error occurred and the connection went down).

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin I shall check tomorrow and let you know the value recvd in recv() function

Comment: @Guillaume send() shows sent bytes as 17312, 1st time recv() gets 11000 bytes, next time recv() returns this error WSAECONNRESET. What could be the problem as send() function has sent all the bytes..

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx.  It means that the sender closed the connection in non graceful way.  So your problem is not with your receiver but your sender

Comment: @Guillaume Thanks I got the problem, my code always assumed that I would receive the message in one go and used to close the socket. Now I wait for the whole message before closing socket